# How to extend Shared Address Space Process Model to Devices and Services

Tags: redhawksdr

I tried to generate code for a device changing the implementation type to **SharedLibrary** and renaming the Entry Point to **Device_Name.so**. I was able to generate and build, but in **main.cpp** it kept a main function not a **make_component** to be called by [ComponentHost](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/tree/develop-2.1/redhawk/src/control/sdr/ComponentHost). the device constructors deals with arguments that ComponentHost doesn't, like the Device Manager IOR. I believe this functionality extension implies changing the source code of ComponenHost. Is it part of REDHAWK roadmap? any comments on how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

So are you trying to use the shared process space within a node to communicate between devices and services? Because I don't believe that there is tooling specifically for this yet, but I think there is a way to do this. Just to be clear I haven't tried this, but based on the test used by the bulkio ports to determine local vs remote transport usage, I think this will work.

If you look at the persona pattern, you'll see that there is a Programmable Device which is responsible for loading Persona Devices. Most of the details for this aren't necessary for what you're trying to do, but the pattern should be helpful. To accomplish communication between Devices using shared memory, you could generate a Programmable device whose sole purpose is to forward parameters from the DeviceManager to the Personas. The Personas would then act as your normal Devices normally do, just launched in the same process space as one another.

The code generators for the Programmable and Persona Devices are not yet integrated into the IDE, so you'll have to create a new Device project in eclipse for each Device you want (so that you'll have the spd files). Be sure to add the appropriate AggregateDevice interface to your Devices. This let's the framework know that multiple devices can technically be considered one entity, but you can also individually communicate with each. Also make sure that the Programmable is an Executable Device, since it needs to launch the Persona Devices. Then, from the command line, you can run `redhawk-codegen - - pgdevice </path/to/programmable/spd>` to generate a Programmable Device, and `redhawk-codegen - - persona </path/to/persona/spd>` to generate your Persona Device(s).

Once all of this is done, you'll notice the main function for your Programmable launches the Device like you described in your question. However, the main function for the Personas has code to launch the Device as either a standalone Device or as simply an object in its own thread.

This should allow the bulkio ports of the Programmable and Personas to communicate with each other via shared memory. Obviously this will break down if you attempt to push data out of the process, at least until someone adds interprocess shared memory via something like shm. Not sure if that's on the road map, but it would certainly be neat.

Update: It appears that interprocess shared memory was added in RH 2.1.2, so you should be able to communicate between collocated Devices, Services, and Components using that mechanism. This renders the above unnecessary, but I'm going to leave it for earlier versions of RH.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Mr Wolfram, I appreciate your detailed answer. it might be promessing. In fact, I would like a share memory transport layer not only within a node or within a waveform/application.. It would be interesting if Node Devices and Application Components could communicate this way. This might be too much to ask for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of RH 2.1.2, the default behavior for Devices/Services/Components whose user code uses redhawk::buffer for the data memory allocator and the stream API for interaction with the bulkio port is to use a shared memory transport between C++ entities that are running in different processes

Comment: There are any restriction to use such shared buffer? I mean.. it only works with bulkio.. or I can use it with another interface with an action that uses _PortTypes_ types like _UshortSequence_ or _FloatSequence_

Comment: Unfortunately no, it can't be used by other interfaces. The shared memory transport is limited to bulkio only